# BitsTransfer (BITS) service and events / WMI

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wmi, windows-server-2016, bits

Older versions of MS Windows had BITS Service exposed on WMI in "root\Microsoft\BITS" namespace. However since MS Windows Server 2012 this namespace is gone.

Is there any "new" way to control BITS using WMI ? I was not able to google or find any namespace which has BITS exposed.

If not, is there any other way to listen to BITS events ?

I would like get events on BITS session start, complete, error, etc. instead of polling this information using C++ app and .dll